# Trouble fixing C Compilation Environment Error when installing Python's Mageck package

Tags: python, c, terminal

I'm trying to install the MAGeCK package (used for analyzing CRISPR screens and the effects of gene knockouts on cellular pathways). When I try to install it in a terminal session with "python3 setup.py install," terminal returns:

"CRITICAL: error compiling the RRA source code. Please check your c compilation environment."

I'm following the instructions in [this two minute video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0FLWSp1tdTI) but my terminal returns this error at about the 1:32 mark. The video is a bit old but I don't think that should affect anything. The person in the video has a Mac I think and I also have a Mac.

Here, I've attached the [link to the package author's Github](https://github.com/davidliwei/mageck/blob/master/rra/Makefile) where he specifies the compiler requirements of the package.

I've also been looking at the "Extension names and packages" section of this website (http://davis.lbl.gov/Manuals/PYTHON-2.3.3/dist/setup-script.html) and the "Building C and C++ extension with distutils" section of this website (https://docs.python.org/3/extending/building.html).

I've been told that this package is hard-coded to use gcc/g++, and so I installed gcc using homebrew (using the code '''brew install gcc''' in my home directory).

Comment: Also here's a paper that gives an overview of the package and has some instructions for how to install it https://sci-hub.se/10.1038/s41596-018-0113-7

Comment: That repo is quite old, and it seems to have moved to https://bitbucket.org/liulab/mageck/src/master/. Also it looks like someone has [reported](https://bitbucket.org/liulab/mageck/issues/16/error-mageck-install-rra-code) your exact issue in that repo, although it has gone without much activity. Finally I suggest you use python 2 to run the program. It doesn't look like it was designed with python 3

Comment: @smac89 Thank you for your advice. I did happen to see that the repo had been migrated but I didn’t see that other report. The paper linked in the comments seems to mention python 3.6 or newer (I think, I don’t have it in front of me though) but it is possible there is some inaccuracy somewhere

Comment: Also I’m especially curious about how you can specify you C compiler when your installing python packages in the terminal - even if an answer can only be made about that, I would be very grateful

Comment: Try `which cc`. It it is a link to `C` compiler that is used as a default.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will be helpful for anyone. But my dad was able to help me out with this and it works for me. I'm using the iMac with M1 Silicon Chip on macOS Monterey 12.2. After running into this issue, I first:

1. Installed gcc with homebrew
2. Aliased gcc and g++ to the homebrew directory with:
   alias gcc=/opt/homebrew/bin/gcc-10
   alias g++=/opt/homebrew/bin/gcc-11
3. Removed the mageck folder (start over from tarred file following wiki installation guidelines)
4. Untar file following installation guidelines.
5. Navigate to >rra > src.
6. Remove all .o files using "rm *.o"
7. Return to rra directory and makefile using "make"
8. Repeat steps exactly within the gsea file (instead of rra, do it on gsea).
9. Then if all good, run "python3 setup.py install". If permission is denied, I ran "sudo python3 setup.py install". This requires your administrator's password.
10. Additionally, RRA and mageckGSEA need to be copied added to the correct path
11. Navigate to bin: “cd bin”
12. Run: sudo cp RRA /usr/local/bin/
13. Run: sudo cp mageckGSEA /usr/local/bin/
14. Hope this helps! still in the process of making sure working correctly You need to install numpy and scipy too. As of right now, all the demos work for me.

Comment: This also worked on an M2 Mac running Ventura, thanks (+1). The  `*.o` object files provided in the package are evidently compiled for the old Intel architecture, and don't seem to work even if Rosetta 2 is installed. The above instructions remove them and regenerate them properly for the Mac arm64 architecture.